# New Google URL open up when I type google.com

Tags: google-search

When I type in `google.com`, it redirects me to this URL: https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=LMQxUoCCO8qfiQfSl4HgAw

What does `&ei=LMQxUoCCO8qfiQfSl4HgAw` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search parameters and what they indicate:
**gws** =Google web server

**rd**=redirected

**cr**=country

Source:[Yahoo Answers from India](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130719135219AAtg143)

**ei** parameter indicates:

Obviously something that needs to be encoded. There’s some suggestion that this shows if the visitor has navigated the Google search pages by clicking “next”. But if “cd” really does mean I was ranked third, then the visitor wouldn’t have needed to click on the next link? Unless I was the third result on the second, third, etc. page?

Source:[Deconstructing Google url search parameters](http://www.t75.org/2012/06/deconstructing-googles-url-search-parameters/)

Hope this helps!